# Excel List of Names and Job Titles

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet containing over 30,000 names. The same 50 or so names are repeated over and over with different information relating to each name on different line. I need to attach the job title to each name so it can be populated out in a pivot table. Is there anyway I can get excel to realize that every time I have Jane Doe's name in column A, I want a specific job title to be in column B? Hopefully without copying and pasting this like I currently am doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Macro To Lookup a User Entered String, and return data from the field next to it](http://superuser.com/questions/486930/excel-macro-to-lookup-a-user-entered-string-and-return-data-from-the-field-next)

Comment: @Excellll - That question looks like it should be a duplicate but it is actually a poorly written question that means something different.  The explanation of what the question means is buried in a comment on one of the answers.  Even if it was the same, it is missing the "recommended answer", which this question has.  I voted to close that question because it will be a source of confusion for people who find it.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a simple **VLOOKUP()** table elsewhere in the worksheet.  You can populate column **B** using this table.

For example:

[image]

Comment: @fixer1234  See my update.................

Comment: I would add a couple of sentences explaining how the formula works, but I love the job titles. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, `VLOOKUP` is not optimal for a number of [reasons described here](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) (doesn't adapt to inserted or expanded columns, uses relative rather than actual column reference, can't handle right to left lookups, etc.). A more robust solution is a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$6,MATCH($A2,$F$2:$F$6,0))
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

It's even better to use an actual table for your lookup list so that 1) the formulas are easier to follow and 2) it automatically expands if you add items without having to go update formulas somewhere else.

```
=INDEX(tblTitles[Title],MATCH($A2,tblTitles[Name],0))
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

The benefits of using a table are described [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-reasons-to-use-excels-table-object/).  Note that you can't just use a table reference formula, you need to create the table, which requires a few setup steps.  If you are not familiar with tables, in addition to Excel help, here is a [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Tables-Using-Microsoft-Excel) and a complete reference is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-structured-references-in-Excel-table-formulas-75fb07d3-826a-449c-b76f-363057e3d16f?CorrelationId=0bcefec5-e658-4c44-a932-7e9f01112288&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).